# Particles on canvas are drawn, but not animating?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Circles on canvas are drawn but have no motion despite calling moveCircle() function. Below you'll find the `class Circle` with the properties, the `class CircleFactory` that generates the circles with those properties and stores them into an array, and the `animate()` function that iterates through the array of circles and is responsible for drawing and moving them. Please run the code snippet in full screen.

```js
//Canvas
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

//get Context
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//Circle class
class Circle {
 constructor(x, y, speedX, speedY){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.r = 30;
  this.speedX = speedX;
  this.speedY = speedY;
 }
}  

class CircleFactory {
 constructor(){
  this.circles = [];
 }
 
 generateCircles(numOfCir){
  const { circles } = this;

  for (let i = 0; i < numOfCir; i++) {
   let xPos = Math.random() * canvas.width;
   let yPos = Math.random() * canvas.height;
   const newCircle = new Circle( xPos, yPos, 1, -2); 
   circles.push(newCircle);
  }
 }

 moveCircles({x, y, r, speedX, speedY}) {
  if (x + speedX > canvas.width - r || x + speedX < r) {
   speedX = -speedX;
  }
  if (y + speedY > canvas.height - r || y + speedY < r) {       
   speedY = -speedY;
  }
  x += speedX;
  y += speedY;      
 }

 drawCircles({x, y, r}) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF80AA';
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2 );
  ctx.stroke();
 }
}

const shape = new CircleFactory
shape.generateCircles(2);

const animate = () => {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 shape.circles.forEach(circle => {
  shape.moveCircles(circle);
  shape.drawCircles(circle);
 })
 window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `moveCircles({x, y, r, speedX, speedY})`, because you're destructuring the circle object, you're not actually updating its state, you're just modifying local variables that are subsequently discarded. Instead, write it as `moveCircles(circle)`, and refer to the coordinates and speed as `circle.x`, `circle.y`, and so on.